Monitoring a dir for a series of steps using inotify
So I am trying to monitor a directory and detect all the events happening to it's files.
I am using inotify in C to achieve that. Ultimately I want to detect a specific series of steps:
1) It first reads the entire content of a file: example.txt
2) It then creates a new file based on the original filename and appends .locked to to the new filename: 
     example.txt.locked
3) It writes the encrypted content to the new file
4) It deletes the original file.

In order to detect those series of steps, I thought of inserting all events, along with the file names, into a linked list and after each event search the list for those 4 events with the same filename.
The problem I encountered with this approach is that the list "resets" every new event. What I mean by "resets" is that it correctly inserts the first event and then when another event happens it inserts that event and without keeping the former one. It's not a data structure problem, or at least I think it is not, because I tested the list I made outside the inotify api and it works fine.
Here's the code:
void monitor_dir(char* base_path){

    int fd, wd;
    int buf_len = 1024 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + 16);
    char buffer[buf_len];

    fd = inotify_init();
    if(fd == -1){
        sprintf(stderr, "inotify_init failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, base_path, IN_ACCESS | IN_CREATE | IN_MODIFY | IN_DELETE);
    if(wd == -1){
        sprintf(stderr, "inotify_add_watch failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct inotify_event* event;
    char* event_name;

    while(1){  

        int len, i = 0;
        len = read(fd, buffer, buf_len);

        if(len < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "read failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while(i < len){
            event = (struct inotify_event*)&buffer[i];
            if (event->len) {
                event_name = malloc(strlen(event->name));
                event_name = event->name;

                // insert a node for each event that happened
                if(event->mask & IN_ACCESS){
                    inf_insert(head, event_name, ACCESS);
                    printf("File accessed: %s\n", event_name);
                }
                if(event->mask & IN_CREATE){
                    inf_insert(head, event_name, CREATE);
                    printf("File created: %s\n", event_name);  
                }
                                  
                if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY){
                    inf_insert(head, event_name, MODIFY);
                    printf("File modified: %s\n", event_name); 
                }               
                if(event->mask & IN_DELETE){
                    inf_insert(head, event_name, DELETE);
                    printf("File deleted: %s\n", event_name);
                }
                
            }
            i += buf_len + event->len;

            // print the list and it's length for debugging
            inf_print(head);
            printf("length: %d\n", inf_getLength(head));
        }

    }

    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    close(fd);

}

It is called by main with the directory path given as a command line argument.
Also, here's the struct for the list and it's functions:
enum state{

    IDLE,
    ACCESS,
    CREATE,
    MODIFY,
    DELETE,
    FINISHED

};

typedef struct list{

    char* filename;
    enum state type;
    struct list* next;

}inf_t;

inf_t* inf_new(){

    inf_t* new;
    new = (inf_t*)malloc(sizeof(inf_t));
    new->filename = NULL;
    new->type = IDLE;
    new->next = NULL;

    return new;

}

int inf_getLength(inf_t* head){

    inf_t* curr = head;
    int counter = 0;

    while(curr != NULL){
        counter++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return counter;

}

int inf_insert(inf_t* head, char* filename, enum state type){

    inf_t* current = head;
    inf_t* temp;

    while(current != NULL){         
        if(current->filename == filename)
            return 0;
        current = current->next;
    }

    current = head;
    temp = inf_new();
    temp->filename = filename;
    temp->type = type;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = temp;

    return 1;

}

void inf_print(inf_t* head){

    inf_t* curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL){
        if(curr->filename != NULL)
            printf("file: %s, type: %d\n", curr->filename, curr->type);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

}

If there's something off with my list implementation do say so.
I really need help with this, I'm kinda stuck. If there's a better way (without inserting every event into a list) to detect the steps mentioned above I am all ears.
Thank you in advance.

event_name = malloc(strlen(event->name)); event_name = event->name; is a memory leak. Use event_name = strdup(event->name) instead.

i += buf_len + event->len; I don't think you want to be adding buf_len there...
